# Download processmaker version 4 comunity edicion

Tags: processmaker

I wanted to know how it is possible to obtain a community version of processmaker v4, I have searched but I cannot find where to download it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that should help:

https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/install-processmaker/installation-guide

https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/releases

Although to start I suggest getting the docker version.
https://github.com/ProcessMaker/pm4core-docker